# Крестики-Нолики. Вывести фигуру несколько раз. matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Вся игра крестики-нолики происходит в консоли. Не знаю как реализовать вывод картинки несколько раз. То есть, ходит игрок крестиком, вывод обновленной картинки. Сходил компьютер ноликом-> вывод картинки. В функции `setting` идет настройка игрового поля и его вывод. А далее в функции `display_board` должна быть отрисовка крестика или нолика в зависимости от хода, но он ничего не выводит в этой функции.
Вот полный код программы

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D  

class Game:
    X = "X"
    O = "O"
    EMPTY = " "
    NUM_SQUARES = 9
    TIE = "TIE"
    xCircle = [0.5,1.5,2.5,0.5,1.5,2.5,0.5,1.5,2.5]
    yCircle = [2.5,2.5,2.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,0.5,0.5,0.5]
    radius = 0.5

    xLine = [[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[0,1],[1,2],[2,3]]
    yLine = [[2,3],[2,3],[2,3],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]]
    fig = plt.figure()    
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')
    color = 'k'
    fill =False
    def setting(self):   

        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')
        self.ax.set_xticks([1,2,3])
        self.ax.set_yticks([1,2,3])
        self.ax.tick_params(axis='both', left='off', top='off', right='off', bottom='off', labelleft='off', labeltop='off', labelright='off', labelbottom='off')
        self.ax.grid()
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.1)
    def ask_yes_no(self,question):
        """Задаёт вопрос с ответом 'Да' или 'Нет'."""
        response = None
        while response not in ("y", "n"):
            response = input(question).lower()
        return response


    def ask_number(self,question, low, high):
        """Просит ввести число из диапазона"""
        response = None
        while response not in range(low, high):
            response = int(input(question))
        return response


    def pieces(self):
        """Определяет принадлежность перового хода."""
        go_first = self.ask_yes_no("Играть крестиками? (y, n): ")
        if go_first == "y":
            print("\n Вы играете кректиками.")
            human = self.X
            computer = self.O
        else:
            print("\n Вы играете ноликами")
            computer = self.X
            human = self.O
        return computer, human


    def new_board(self):
        """Создаёт новую игровую доску."""
        board = []
        for square in range(self.NUM_SQUARES):
            board.append(self.EMPTY)
        return board


    def display_board(self,board):
        """Отображает игровую доску на экране."""
        for i in range(self.NUM_SQUARES):
            if (board[i]!=self.EMPTY):
                if (board[i]==self.X):
                    line = Line2D(self.xLine[i], self.yLine[i],color='k')
                    self.ax.add_line(line)
                    plt.draw()
                    plt.pause(0.1)
                if (board[i]==self.O):
                    self.ax.add_artist(plt.Circle((self.xCircle[i], self.yCircle[i]), self.radius, color=self.color, fill=self.fill))
                    plt.draw()
                    plt.pause(0.1)
    def legal_moves(self,board):
        """Создаёт список доступных ходов."""
        moves = []
        for square in range(self.NUM_SQUARES):
            if board[square] == self.EMPTY:
                moves.append(square)
        return moves


    def winner(self,board):
        """Определяет победителя в игре."""
        WAYS_TO_WIN = ((0, 1, 2),
                       (3, 4, 5),
                       (6, 7, 8),
                       (0, 3, 6),
                       (1, 4, 7),
                       (2, 5, 8),
                       (0, 4, 8),
                       (2, 4, 6))
        for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:
            if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != self.EMPTY:
                winner = board[row[0]]
                return winner
            if self.EMPTY not in board:
                return self.TIE
        return None


    def human_move(self,board, human):
        """Получает ход человека"""
        legal = self.legal_moves(board)
        move = None
        while move not in legal:
            move = self.ask_number("Твой ход. Выбери одно из полей (0 - 8):", 0, self.NUM_SQUARES)
            if move not in legal:
                print("\nЭто поле уже занято. Выбери другое.\n")
        return move


    def computer_move(self,board, computer, human):
        """Делает ход за компьютерного противника."""
        # создадим рабочую копию доски, потому что функция будет менять некотороые элементы в списке
        board = board[:]
        # ходы, от лучшего к худшему
        BEST_MOVES = (4, 0, 2, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7)

        print("Я выберу поле номер", end = " ")
        # если сдедующим ходом может победить компьютер, выберем этот ход
        for move in self.legal_moves(board):
            board[move] = computer
            if self.winner(board) == computer:
                print(move)
                return move
            # выполнив проверку этого хода, отменим его (в локальной копии игровой доски)
            board[move] = self.EMPTY

        # если следующим ходом может победить чегловек, блокируем этот ход
        for moves in self.legal_moves(board):
            board[move] = human
            if self.winner(board) == human:
                print(move)
                return move
            # выполнив проверку этого хода, отменим его (в локальной копии игровой доски)
            board[move] = self.EMPTY

        # поскольку следующим ходом ни одна из сторон не может победить,
        # выберем лучшее из доступных полей
        for move in BEST_MOVES:
            if move in self.legal_moves(board):
                print(move)
                return move


    def next_turn(self,turn):
        """Осуществляет переход хода."""
        if turn == self.X:
            return self.O
        else:
            return self.X


    def congrat_winner(self,the_winner, computer, human):
        """Поздравляет победителя игры."""
        if the_winner == computer:
            print("Вы проиграли!")
        elif the_winner == human:
            print("Вы выиграли!")
        elif the_winner == self.TIE:
            print("Ничья!")     
    def main(self):        
        computer, human = self.pieces()
        self.setting()
        turn = self.X
        board = self.new_board()
        while not self.winner(board):
            if turn == human:
                move = self.human_move(board, human)
                board[move] = human
            else:
                move = self.computer_move(board, computer, human)
                board[move] = computer
            self.display_board(board)
            turn = self.next_turn(turn)
        the_winner =self.winner(board)
        self.congrat_winner(the_winner, computer, human)
plt.ion()
# запуск программы
clas=Game()
clas.main()
#input("Нажмите Enter, чтобы выйти.")
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91001/discussion-on-question-by-andrei-sever-----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В моем случае использовалась Anaconda со Spider. И поэтому функция `plt.draw()` при второй отрисовке выдавала следующее `<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>`. Решение: установил модуль `matplotlib` в IDLE 3.7 . Строка установки - пишем в консоли `pip install matplotlib`. После запустил программу в IDLE 3.7 и повторная отрисовка заработала.